# Securing user-data - for use in method calls, SQL and file calls

Tags: php, security, validation, user-input

I am using `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` variables in method calls, SQL queries and file calls - and it is necessary to escape / rewrite this user-data for better security (avoid injection attacks and the like). How would you recommend this is done?

Some ideas from built-in escape function ... to get the juices flowing:

- Add backslashes to: `\x00, \n, \r, \, ', "` and `\x1a` to make the string safe for SQL queries - as in mysql_real_escape_string().
- Limit the number of accepted characters to `[a-zA-Z0-9 _-\.]` (where "`\.`" is an escaped "."-dot).

Your inputs are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As escaping depends on the system you are sending the data too, my suggestion would be to use the functions provided by PHP, specifically created for each system.

For instance :

- for MySQL queries, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), or [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), or [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

  - Or use prepared statements ([mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php))
  - Don't add backslashes yourself : why do that when proper and well-working (and well-tested !) escaping functions already exist ?
- for HTML output, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Either way : don't re-invent the wheel !

There are escaping functions/methods that already exists for many kind of output : use those !

Comment: make sure you connect to mysql before usint the mysql_* functions above, if you are using mysql that is..

Comment: Don’t put a space before colons, question marks and exclamation marks. That looks awful!

Comment: @Gumbo: sorry about that; I usually type in french, and, in french, we put a space before those... And I don't have the reflex to remove those spaces when typing in english...

Answer (score 0):

Also note that somethings you must escape (if user entered) are image locations etc

If someone hot linked to an image (for example an avatar) with this

> http://yoursite.com/admin/user/delete/1

and then the code in your view is

```
<img class="avatar" alt="<?php echo $userName; ?>" src="<?php $avatarUrl; ?>" />
```

Then you might be accidentally deleting a user if you are logged in as admin. Of course, hopefully that sort of deletion is done with a post, but it can still be circumvented.

In this case, `htmlspecialchars()` won't help.

You can make it harder for an attacker by enforcing all data changing methods to be with a post, and you can make it almost impossible by generating a token for every delete action, and verifying it before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using like this:

```
function escape($sql) {
    // Stripslashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $sql = stripslashes($sql);
    }
    //if this is the intedger
    if (!is_int($sql) || $sql == '0') {
        $sql = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($sql) . "'";
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

And in MySQL query

```
mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM `page` WHERE `id` = ".escape($_GET['id'])." LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: This function will only work for SQL queries - not for method  and file calls - also, it is MySQL-specific. It must be possible to make a more generic Escape function.